# Change letter spacing in PostScript

Tags: fonts, postscript, eps

In writing a postscript file, one can select a font like this:

```
/Courier-Bold findfont 16 scalefont setfont
(bar baz) show
```

I would like to change the letter spacing of my font - is there a way to do that? Either directly as a font operator, or perhaps just by being able to insert arbitrary postscript commands between glyph rendering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are several variants of the `show` operator that can be used for things like this:

- a<sub>x</sub> a<sub>y</sub> string   **ashow**   - 
  add (*a<sub>x</sub>, a<sub>y</sub>*) to width of each char while showing *string*
- c<sub>x</sub> c<sub>y</sub> char string   **widthshow**   - 
  add (*c<sub>x</sub>, c<sub>y</sub>*) to width of *char* while showing *string*
- c<sub>x</sub> c<sub>y</sub> char a<sub>x</sub> a<sub>y</sub> string   **awidthshow**   - 
  combine effects of ashow and widthshow
- proc string   **kshow**   - 
  execute *proc* between characters shown from *string*

A few tips. Since postscript doesn't have character literals, a common idiom is to extract the integer value from a 1-byte string literal to supply the *char* argument for `widthshow` and `awidthshow`. Eg.

```
( ) 0 get %the space char, aka 32 or 16#20
```

And unless you're going for some kind of stair-case effect, all the <sub>y</sub> values should be 0.

The proc executed by kshow between each character receives as arguments the char-just-shown and the char-about-to-be-shown, in that order. This is presumably to allow you to look up the pair in some kind of "kerning table". But I've never actually seen this done. But remember to pop them if they're not needed (usually).

---

As for making a derived font, I refer you to [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/output-a-playable-crossword-grid/3948#3948) on codegolf.SE which creates a Crossword Font by drawing boxes around Times-Roman. The width of the character is declared with the setcachedevice operator in the /BuildChar procedure. For mine, I just needed a constant width so I used 1 to tie it directly to the font size.